# postgres \dt functionality change from v9.4 to 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a postgres 9.4 database and when I use the:

```
\dt
```

command, tables in the 'public' schema, **and** other user-created schemas are shown.

I have the exact same database on a Postgres 9.6 server and when I use:

```
\dt
```

only the tables in the 'public' schema are shown, and in order to see tables in the other user-created schema, i have to use:

```
\dt schemaname.*
```

to see those tables. Is this a difference between 9.4 and 9.6, or any i missing something else. permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the search_path for each user you're trying to check on.

```
SHOW search_path;
```

If they're different you can set them with `SET search_path TO mySchema, public;`

Comment: this is what i needed. incidentally, my real problem appeared to be the fact that i had capital letters and an unserscore '_' in my schema name, and that was throwing a wrench into the works.

Comment: Yeah the whole folding to lower (or upper) case thing in SQL bites a lot of folks int he butt. Glad you got it sussed.